# How to create installer to the network folder using IzPack

Tags: java, jenkins, izpack

I'm using IzPack plugin to generate the installer of a project done in java. 
I use continuous integration with Jenkins.

My scenario is as follows: 
On my computer I can usually generate a build using the maven but when committing and make jenkins run to build the installer tries to create the directory in which I add, the same happens the following error below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-5:izpack (standard-installer) on project ManagerNeverStop: Could not create directory \\192.168.2.6\deploy\produto\testes -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-5:izpack (standard-installer) on project ManagerNeverStop: Could not create directory \\192.168.2.6\deploy\produto\testes
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not create directory \\192.168.2.5\deploy\Manager_NeverStop\testes
    at org.izpack.mojo.IzPackMojo.init(IzPackMojo.java:181)
    at org.izpack.mojo.IzPackMojo.execute(IzPackMojo.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 30 more
```

My pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
                    <customPanelDirectory>${staging.dir}</customPanelDirectory>
                    <installerFile>\\192.168.2.6\teste\/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${prefix.revision}-install</installerFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>standard-installer</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>izpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My problem is how to generate an installer on a mapped network directory using IzPack and Jenkins.

I've looked at the permissions and the same are with full permission.

Comment: Does the Jenkins user have the required permissions to connect the network drive and make directories?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I see this setting?

Comment: Under what user profile does jenkins run as?  Login as that user and see if you can browse over to the network driver, see if you can make directories on that drive.  You may also consider mapping the drive instead of using a UNC path, which will only work under Windows